# ant.design v5.2.0 - date.locale is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd, dayjs

I have the following problem:

I am using ant.design in version 5.2.0. When I use the  component as follows, I always get the attached error message when I pass a date to  for the Form.Item in dayjs format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keiQn.png)

If I don't specify the default value as dayjs `<form>` I don't get an error, but I also don't get a prefilled value in the datepicker.

What else can I try?

Here is an excerpt of the source code:

```
<Form
    form={formRef}
    onFinish={handleSubmit}
    initialValues={{...collaboration, dueDate: dayjs(collaboration.dueDate)}}
>
    <Form.Item label="DatePicker" name={"dueDate"} rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select time!' }]}>
         <DatePicker style={{width: "100%"}}/>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: Your code look fine. Can you please create a code sandbox?

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error when I was trying to set a string value to Datepicker:

example form init value:

```
values = {
   //other values
   ...
   start:'2023-12-12 13:00:00',

   end:'2023-12-15 09:00:00'
}
```

I had to convert my dates string using dayjs:

```
 import dayjs from 'dayjs';
 ...
 let date_fields = ['start','end'];
 for(let field of date_fields){
    values[field] = values[field]? dayjs(values[field]):null;
 }
 // now is safe to init form
 form.setFieldsValue(values);
```

Comment: I got the same, only with initialValues. I consider this unexpected behaviour in the datepicker component

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sandbox for this case:
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-4mv33s?file=/index.js

Edit:
It works in the sandbox :D

Comment: Since, you are posting an answer as an update to your own question, you can directly edit the question and put the link in there.

Comment: Oh okay. Didn’t thought about that. 

I already found a solution :) I will post it in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

***Here is my code***
** it is working for me **
antdesign v5

- datepicker of form values will not accept string;

```js
const dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY";

const init = {
    dateOfBirth: dayjs(),
  };

<Form
   layout="vertical"
   hideRequiredMark
   onFinish={(values) => console.log(values)}
   initialValues={init}
 >
    <Form.Item label="Date Of Birth" name="dateOfBirth">
       <DatePicker format={dateFormat} />
    </Form.Item>
 </Form>
```

Comment: how is your dateFormat define?

Comment: just added the date format.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in table `columns` config, when I change the `key` value from `createdAt` to `created_at`, it throws this error.

However I can change it to `created_at_123`. Some values may be used internally by the component. It is not mentioned in the docs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use moment :)

This error occurs because the value you are trying to fill in is off the default date picker setting.
When I used the datepicker without prefilled data it works but when you have to edit something for example in a modal this error appears.
I fixed it with

npm install moment

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

And to fix your specific error:

your function, where you set the form data:

```
    form.setFieldsValue({
      ...formnamehere,
      dueDate: moment(collaboration.dueDate),
    });
```